# Странное поведение словаря, созданного из fromkeys

Tags: python, словари

коллеги!
Просветите меня, пожалуйста, за странное поведение аппенда в ключ словаря, созданного из fromkeys:

```
def hash_as_key(obj):
    x = {}.fromkeys([hash(i) for i in obj], [])
    [x[hash(j)].append(j) for j in obj]
    return {k:v if len(v) != 1 else v[0] for k, v in x.items()}

print(hash_as_key([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]))
```

Требуемый вывод: `{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: [5, 5]}`

Фактический вывод: `{1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5], 3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5], 4: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5], 5: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]}`

Аппендится весь список, вместо конкретного значения из списка.
При этом, если создавать словарь через defaultdict - все работает как требуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совершенно нормальное поведение, строго по докстрингу:

> Signature: dict.fromkeys(iterable, value=None, /)
> Docstring: Create a new dictionary with keys from iterable and **values set to value**.

Все значения словаря устанавливаются указанным вами значением. А значение у вас - один конкретный пустой список. В результате, все значения этого словаря указывают на **один и тот же список**.

Хотите задать в качестве значений **разные** списки - используйте, например, словарное сокращение (или как это правильно называется):

```py
x = {hash(i):[] for i in obj}
```

Ну или `defaultdict(list)`, тогда списки тоже будут разные, да.

Да, и зачем вы, собственно, используете `hash` в явном виде я тоже не понял. Плюсов тут никаких, но есть риск нарваться на коллизию хэшэй. Словарь и так сам под капотом будет использовать `hash`, а в случае коллизии - явное сравнение объектов, чего у вас и нет. Например, можете глянуть, чему внезапно равен `hash(-1)`, ну и другие интересные случаи могут быть.

Comment: Вы правы, дошло! Это же один общий список... Благодарю!

Comment: @AlexanderVi Ну, это одна из типовых ловушек питона. Нужно понимать, когда в коде список инициализируется однократно, а когда на каждой итерации некоего цикла отдельно. )

Comment: Понимаю, смысла сохранять хэши нет, данную функцию использовал только как пример для реализации различных алгоритмов словарей и сначала недопонял, что в fromkeys всем значениям дается список с одним id.